# find mean for every n rows in table by few columns?

Tags: r

I have a case - table like

```
    date v1 v2
    1991 1  2
    1991 1  3
    1991 2  1
    1991 2  3
    1992 1  1

etc
```

and I need to find mean for v2 for every 2 rows with same pair of date-v1

I have no idea, because I know

```
aggregate(df$v2, by = list(df$date), mean)
```

but my task is different and as output I need something like

```
    date v1 v2
    1991 1  2.5
    1991 2  2
    1992 1  1
etc
```

Comment: Reopen rationale: I didn't see that cited question as being a duplicate. The questioner clearly wanted the last `v1==1` to NOT be in the same grouping as the other two `v1==1` rows. The cited question would have wanted them together. If the question is only based on paired data-v1 groups then there probably are duplicated questions out there, but if it's only based on the adjacent v1 values that are the same then it might be harder to find a dupe. @DmitryGolubev: You should clarify the rule to be used and make a bigger example but only in the case that it is the latter rule.

Answer (score 1):

> aggregate(df$v2, by = list(df$date), mean)

You could modify this and extend it to multiple variables in order to solve your problem:

```
aggregate(df, by = list(df$date,df$v1), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `rollapply` function from `zoo` package is very handy in such scenario.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(df)
#width = 2, by = 2 for adjacent rows. 
rollapply(z, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE, by = 2, partial = TRUE)

#   date v1  v2
# 1 1991  1 2.5
# 3 1991  2 2.0
# 5 1992  1 1.0
```

**Update**

Seems OP wants to calculate `mean` for every `n` row of his choice. In that way use of `v1` column should be avoided.

One option using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 2  #It can be set as 3, 4 etc. Number of row for which mean is needed
df %>%
  group_by(date, everyN = ceiling(row_number()/n)) %>%
  summarise(v2 = mean(v2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"date v1 v2
1991 1  2
1991 1  3
1991 2  1
1991 2  3
1992 1  1", header = T)
```

Comment: This doesn’t works with empty warnings on big dataset(

Comment: @DmitryGolubev Has your dataset got `NA` in it?

Comment: @DmitryGolubev Probably you should try my 2nd option then.

Comment: with v1 is the main problem i have, it's like user's ID, and full case is seatching mean of t1 for every few dates per v1. But anyway thanks